# Help with a proof regarding a function based on a procedurally generated sequence of numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

My problem is the following. It is purely recreational, not from any sort of homework or anything I have seen before.
I will start by defining the function, from here on referred to as f(x). Where x is an integer greater than 1.

f(x) is the set of unique pairs of integers generated in the following sequence.

Each pair will be shown in the format of (a,b).
Our first pair of numbers will always be (0, 1).
For all subsequent pairs the value of a is the previous value of b, and the value of y will be (a+b)\mod(x).
The sequences for 2, 3, 4, 5 are shown below

2: (0,1), (1,1), (1,0) then repeats

3: (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,1), (1,0) then repeats

4: (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,1), (1,0) then repeats

5: (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (0,3), (3,3), (3,1), (1,4), (4,0), (0,4), (4,4), (4,3), (3,2), (2,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,4), (4,1), (1,0) then repeats.

so f(2) = 3, f(3) = 8, f(4) = 6, f(5) = 20.

I have included the results for 2-20 and prime numbers under 50 at http://pastebin.com/MDSA9ybU

My conjecture is that for for two integers a and b greater than 1. $f(ab)=\frac{f(a)f(b)\gcd(a,b)}{\gcd(f(a),f(b))} = \lcm(f(a),f(b))\gcd(a,b)$

For every test I have done it works, but I have no idea why, and I would like some help proving or disproving it.

I provided code for generating f(x) is at http://pastebin.com/baB6Ynkr

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  OP has stated a clear question and given it substantial thought.

Comment: The downvote has been rescinded.  Maybe it was a misclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are known as the Pisano numbers and shown in [OEIS A001175](http://oeis.org/A001175)  The first line under formula looks like it will take you a long way toward what you want.

Comment: It is far to early to accept this answer because it doesn't completely solve your problem.  I am glad it helped, but if you unaccept it you might get something better.  If this led you to a full answer, I would suggest you post that and accept it.  I think an upvote is more appropriate.

Comment: I would upvote but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: In that case, do you think this answer may be more appropriate as a comment (seeing as how it is not all that long and would fit fairly well in a comment thread)? Just a thought. :)

Comment: @crash:  I think it is close between an answer and a comment.  The point about being multiplicative (which is not made explicit in OEIS) seemed to me to be very close to the question.  I have posted partial answers a number of times hoping somebody else would finish the job.  Sometimes it works.

Comment: Fair point. I was largely going off of your own comment. I was the one who misclicked by accident. Oops! +1 all around.

Comment: f(ab)=f(a)f(b) when a and b are coprime is incorrect. f(3) = 8, f(11)=10, f(33) = 40. I looked a the OEIS formula. It does show the relation between lcm and f(x). I used that and lcm(a,b)=ab/gcf(a,b) and I arrived at f(ab)=f(a)f(b)/(gcd(f(a),f(b))) the only thing missing is my multiplication by gcd(a,b).

Comment: But I would also like to know how they arrived at the formula. Is there some reference that shows their proof?

Comment: You are right, the LCM spoils the multiplicativity.   I haven't followed the links provided to see if there is an answer there.

Comment: My conjecture is false. f(100) != lcm(f(10),f(10))*gcd(10,10)